# What are the effects of playing on Easy?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I've been playing FTL on Normal for several games, and, having had my ass handed to me from sectors 1 to 7, have decided to switch to Easy for a while.

What are the differences between playing on Normal and Easy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy mode will give you more scrap per battle and will reduce the difficulty of battles by lowering the quality of weapons on enemy ships.  Achievements and new ship types can be unlocked in either difficulty and will carry through to both difficulties of the game.

Comment: Good answer, but one thing not mentioned is that the Achievements say whether they were unlocked on Easy or Normal (haven't worked out if they get upscaled if you get them on Normal after getting them on Easy).
People should be warned of the SHAME of getting to Sector 8 on Easy first.

Comment: I was just happy to get to Sector 8 at all! :-)

Comment: You also get more points respectively on Normal mode.

Answer (score 8):

I can't find anything solid on the difficulty settings, there [is a quote from one of the developers of FTL](https://getsatisfaction.com/ftlgame/topics/unbalanced_difficulty_settings) stating that the game is *supposed* to be difficult;

> The game is definitely designed to be hard. We're using the difficulty names not in compared to other games / expectations, but compared to what we've designed the 'typical' experience to be.
>
> 'Normal' is the normal game. It's what the game is designed/balanced for and intended to be.
>
> 'Easy' is for new players or those that prefer a slightly less hardcore experience.
>
> I didn't want to use 'normal' and 'hard' because 'hard' suggests something that most players shouldn't necessarily attempt. In order to experience the game as it was intended it, the player should play (or at least try) 'normal,' hence the name.

[This forum post](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=492030) suggests that the following are adjusted based on which difficulty you select;

- Money received
- Enemies have a chance of having better (deadlier) weapons equipped

As mentioned though, I have nothing from a more solid source.

Comment: My first two games on Easy, I was annihilated by multiple missile wielding starcraft within 2 sectors. Frankly, I'm thinking the difficulty levels should be "Bird on the Wing" and "Hold Me Where I Cannot Stand"

Comment: the only difference that I have detected is more scrap on easy, the ships seem exactly the same sector to sector

Comment: I think I've noticed a difference, but it's slight compared to the fact that you can max out every important bar with less compromises.